# I am Not understanding why im getting output like this : Understanding Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, windows, curly-braces, braces

When i declared some multiple random int variables in the C Programming Language.

**CASE 1** : using `int b=(20,30,400);` when i run the code with specifying round braces without declaring an array properly I'm getting output  as `400`. Which is the last value in that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   
    int b=(20,30,400);

    printf("%d",b);

    return 0;
}
```

**CASE 2** : Using `int b={20,30,400};` when i run the code with specifying curly-braces without declaring an array properly I'm getting output  as `20`. Which is the first value in that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   
    int b={20,30,400};

    printf("%d",b);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to know the exact working with braces in arrays, why it changing it output value.

Comment: `(20,30,400)` this is not array . simply `,` expression with result 400

Comment: Take a look at this: [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do).

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile the second code snippet? Do they tell you what is wrong?

Comment: Case 2 has syntax error, so there won't be an executable file to run. If you want multiple values you can use an array, but you don't have one. It would need to be `int b[] = {20, 30, 400};`, but then `printf("%d", b);` will be incorrect.

Comment: @Machani Omesh, Save time. Enable all warnings.

Comment: Writing up random code "to see what happens" is perhaps not the most efficient way to learn *anything*. You are very likely to run into the dreaded Undefined Behavior, where we can't tell what *should* happen.

Comment: @WeatherVane I initially thought (and commented as such) that snippet 2 won't compile, but gcc compiles it with warnings. `warning: excess elements in scalar initializer`

Comment: It's a shame that any compiler, anywhere compiles CASE 2 under any circumstances because, no way is that legit c, rt?  And allowing it to compile and worse -- run -- just makes the world worse for every living thing on the green earth.

Comment: for seccond code it getting output as  20.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you have this:

```c
    int b=(20,30,400);
```

`(20, 30, 40)` is an expression using the comma operator (twice). The comma operator evaluates the expression on the left-hand side, then the expression on the right-hand side, and has the value of the expression on the right-hand side. Therefore, `(20,30,400)` "evaluates" `20` and `30`, then `400`, and has the value `400`. This is why the first code snippet prints `400`.

Your second code snippet does not seem to be valid C code to me. It compiles with warnings in gcc, even with `-pedantic`, so maybe I'm missing something. Best I can find in the current [draft C23 standard](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) at 6.7.10.12 is this:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces, or it shall be an empty initializer

So I'd say the braces are ok, but you can't have more than one expression inside.